# Error in laravel query builder due to Doctrine\Dbal update

Tags: laravel, dbal

As soon as I updated doctrine/dbal

This is git diff on composer.lock JSON

```
 "name": "doctrine/dbal",
-            "version": "v2.5.5",
+            "version": "v2.5.12",
```

I got error in Laravel Query builder 
undefined method inRandomOrder

```
$query =  $query->inRandomOrder();
```

Comment: What version of laravel are you running according to composer?

Comment: Laravel Framework version 5.2.31